# How to solve the out of memory exception in j2me application

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, out-of-memory, mobile-application

I am developing a mobile application in j2me.

My application performs the following things

- I connect the mobile with the some external device with bluetooth
- Send the data/command to that device via bluetooth
- Receive the response from that device

My problem is the device return the data up to 1000KB. So my application throws "Out of memory " exception.

Please help me to solve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is trivial, that 1MB on chip memory is not available in your device. So try to break your data into chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase your os memory
go through this. http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the size of physical space on a J2ME device, it's memory footprint will vary from 64 to 512kb typically. I think the maximum is actually 512kb for J2ME. Though I could be wrong, I would look into it. It's a common cunfusion, I used to face this problem all the time in my J2ME testing days at Jamdat Mobile. A lot of the Motorola V series devices were especially notorious for throwing this error.

Look at the KVM implementation on the device your using to determine what the true memory footprint is.

You may find this helpful: http://java.sun.com/products/cldc/wp/KVMwp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Note that older J2ME implementations used a non-defragmenting memory manager.  When I made games we had to explicitly order our allocations.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the data on a temporary file so you don't need to keep all the data in the memory?
You can also increase memory allocation but then one day you'll have the same problem again if the user sends an even bigger file.